# Rename Field And Add Field With Same Name In One

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that creates a table, inserts data into the table, and now I need to alter the table to

> 1) Rename an existing field to a new name
>   
> 2) Add a new field with the same name as the field we just renamed

I tried this syntax however my SSMS freezes anytime I execute and I have to ctrl+alt+del to close....I feel that is unrelated to the syntax, but wanted to ask

```
    Create Table TMI (empName varchar(500), userID varchar(100), TV float)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX eNIndex 
ON TMI (empName ASC)

dbo.sp_RENAME '[dbo].TMI.TV' , 'OrigTV', 'COLUMN'

ALTER TABLE [dbo].TMI
ADD TV float;
```

Comment: In general, try using the latest version of SSMS (17.3 as of writing) and you'll find you get far fewer crashes and freezing.

Comment: @LowlyDBA - thanks for the tip!  I will upgrade to a newer version of SSMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things...

The `sp_rename` procedure is in the `sys` schema, not `dbo`.

Second, if you execute a stored procedure in a batch, then you must use the `EXEC` keyword.

Try changing your code to this:

```
CREATE Table TMI (empName varchar(500), userID varchar(100), TV float)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX eNIndex 
ON TMI (empName ASC)

EXEC sys.sp_rename '[dbo].TMI.TV' , 'OrigTV', 'COLUMN'

ALTER TABLE [dbo].TMI
ADD TV float;
```